# Cause of delay after use `$database`

Tags: mysql

For a certain project, it seems like the command `use <database>;` takes an extraordinarily long time (often a minute or more). (This seems to be the case across a couple of different instances on different versions of MySQL (5.3 and 5.5, I think)). I understand that this is caused by the <kbd>Tab</kbd> complete functionality, and I am aware that I could just use a -A flag, but I am interested in the cause of this delay.

My first guess was that this has to do with the speed of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, and that the sheer number of columns caused a delay, but at 4.7k columns (580 tables at ~8 columns a table), that seems a bit of a stretch. There are 3.6k indexes, but that does not strike me as a likely cause of the issue.

Comment: Is your server busy?

Comment: @tadman No. This happens on dev. boxes, so generally one user.

Comment: @tadman Can you put that into an answer? The second connection took probably 1/4 the time of the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've pretty much hit the nail on the head.

If the `use` command results in a change of default database, then the MySQL client [branches into](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql/mysql-server/5.7/view/head:/client/mysql.cc#L4674) `build_completion_hash()`.

Provided that the client was [not started with the `-A` option](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql/mysql-server/5.7/view/head:/client/mysql.cc#L2904), that function:

1. [hashes all SQL commands](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql/mysql-server/5.7/view/head:/client/mysql.cc#L2913);
2. [executes `show databases` and hashes the results](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql/mysql-server/5.7/view/head:/client/mysql.cc#L2921);
3. [executes `show tables` and hashes the results](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql/mysql-server/5.7/view/head:/client/mysql.cc#L2937); and
4. **for *each* table**, [calls `mysql_list_fields()` and hashes the results](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql/mysql-server/5.7/view/head:/client/mysql.cc#L2975).

So, in your case, it is making **582 separate database requests** (one for each of steps 2 and 3; and 580 for step 4), looping over the results of each one.  Ouch.

Of course, it'd have been imminently more sensible to do (or at least first *attempt* to do) a single `SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()` but ours is not to ponder why…

Answer (score 1):

There's a few possibilities I can think of:

- Loading the auto-complete data takes a really long time because you've got a schema that a very large number of tables and columns. Transmitting this isn't always very efficient, so as you note, -A might help. Is it slow connecting to the main `mysql` database?
- Otherwise maybe MySQL was at rest and needs a moment to spin up and get ready for your requests, though this should mean a second connection is much faster. Once the caches are warmed up, which includes the OS-level disk cache, it should perform better. On a lightly-loaded system this will often be the case.

Comment: In this case it was the latter. My guess is that `use <db>;` is triggering a complete rebuild of some indexes. Odd.

Comment: That shouldn't rebuild anything, though I'd keep an eye out for any unusual activity in `SHOW PROCESSLIST`. Maybe it's just having to really work to get going, as your filesystem might be cold.